# SMTP Error - Can't Connect to Network

Tags: php, email, dns, phpmailer

I've been trying to implement SMTP with PHPMailer for about a week now. I'm revising my old mail() php script and am having difficulty even setting up a live test taken right from the example since I keep receiving the same error. I'm currently running a HostGator dedicated server and my MX record (mail server) is through Office 365/Outlook. For some reason, I keep getting the `can't connect to network` error as seen in the image below.

[image]

My code is below which I took from the github SMTP example. I originally used port 587 with 'tls' authentication but this did not work and after speaking with Microsoft they suggested I do port 25 with no authentication. Still the same error. Can anyone explain to me what i'm doing wrong or suggest a better route of approach? Thanks!

Code:

```
 <?
 require(dirname(__FILE__)."/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
 $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
 $mail->Port = 25;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->Username = "jason@***.com";
 $mail->Password = "***";
 $mail->setFrom('jason@***.com', 'Jason');
 $mail->addReplyTo('jason@***.com', 'Jason');
 $mail->addAddress('jason@***.com', 'Jason');
 $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
 $mail->msgHTML($email_message);
 $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
 if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
echo "Message sent!";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm seeing `smtp-mail.outlook.com` referenced as an outgoing SMTP server (`$mail->Host`) on some [Microsoft docs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app). I have no idea if it will work, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Follow the advice in the troubleshooting guide linked to in the error message - that's why it's there. This sounds like a DNS problem - either you're looking for the wrong name, or your DNS service is not working.

Comment: @Synchro I still am not sure about the error. I know you told me to check the troubleshoot guide and everything seems fine. I tried to use mandrill as well and I get the same connect() failed error. Are the three php files only needed for this to work -- class.phpmailer.php, PHPMailerAutoload, and class.smtp.php?

Comment: It sounds like a general network/DNS problem, so it will affect all destinations. Many ISPs block outbound SMTP, so it could be that. There's nothing that PHPMailer can do about it. Yes, those are the only files you need, as it says in the readme.